# exporting mongodb collection into csv having list of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I am having a collection named "Books" and my sub documents like this

```
{
    Country : 'XYZ'
    Books : [
             {"name" : "book1", "url" : "book1url", "auth_email" : "emailid1"},
             {"name" : "book2", "url" : "book2url", "auth_email" : "emailid2"},
             {"name" : "book3", "url" : "book3url", "auth_email" : "emailid3"},
             {"name" : "book4", "url" : "book4url", "auth_email" : "emailid4"}
             ..........................................
           ]
}
```

I want to  export it to a csv file with the following format

```
Country | name | url      | auth_email| name | url       | auth_email | ................
XYZ       book1  book1url   emailid1    book2  book2url   emailid2 ...................
```

I did something like this

```
mongoexport -host localhost -db test -collection Books -csv > TopBooksOnline.csv -f Country,Books.name,Books.url,Books.auth_email
```

But I got empty content in the fields "Books.name", "Books.url" and " Books.auth_email"

If I do this

```
mongoexport -host localhost -db test -collection Books -csv > TopBooksOnline.csv -f Country,Books
```

Then it will club all my sub-docs into one.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the CSV format allows you to split up a single document as multiple documents, as this is something that you would need if you have nested documents. It would most definitely not create multiple fields for each sub-document as you are expecting. If you want to do that, then you can quite easily write your own CSV exporter which allows you a lot more flexibility anyway.